# Shortcut to mark all SMS text messages read?

Tags: sms

Is there an app that has a homescreen shortcut to mark all SMS text messages as read?  Or an app that does this when I run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Go SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) & use its `Mark all read` option (Its in `More` tab of `options` menu). As data container of text messages are shared between apps, changes will be reflected in stock messaging app too.

[image: Go SMS Pro - Mark all read]

Comment: Any option for less clicks? Is there an option to mark the message as read when it's short enough to read it in the notification?

Comment: Go SMS is kind of heavy on my RAM.

Answer (score 1):

**`ChompSMS`** has a "mark all as read" option

Comment: But ChompSMS and it's lightweight analogue Textra SMS don't support dual-sim.